# Raspberry - can't clone from bitbucket using SSH

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Didn't thought I will be stuck here.
Got .ssh key on my win machine: [my user]/.ssh/mybitbucket
Able to clone from bitbucket.org with it

Need to clone project to RaspberryPi

Copy-pasted `mybitbucket` and `mybitbucket.pub` to `~/.ssh` on Raspberry
Then `git clone git@bitbucket.org:[username]/my_utils.git`

and got this:

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts 
(/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any help?

Also added `mybitbucket.pub` to `authorized_keys`, but can't connect to Raspberry from Xshell with SSH key for reason unknown to me. Just choosing my key from options, click OK, the connection window blinks and nothing happens

EDIT:

Just for an experiment I generated a new key on Raspberry and added it to bitbucket - that worked. Though how to add existing keys?

Comment: This looks like a general issue with `ssh` setup, rather than anything git related.  (That is, if you use `ssh` directly to remote from the raspberry pi to ... well, anything really... I expect you'll get the same error.)  It looks like a file permissions error.  (Note that each time you connect to a new host with ssh, some data about that host is recorded under your .ssh directory.)

Comment: @phd, instruction didn't helped

Comment: Run this: command `: >>/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts`. If you get `Permission denied`, then figure out with `ls -l` which of `/`, `/home`, `/home/pi`, `/home/pi/.ssh`, `/home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts` has incorrect owner, group or insufficient permissions, and fix them with `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: I checked all rights, generated a new key with `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa` and it's working with a new one - I can clone. Just for an experiment, I renamed my copy-pasted keys to `id_rsa` - it worked. So looks like it doesn't see keys with names other than `id_rsa`. Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts
>
> Also added mybitbucket.pub to authorized_keys, but can't connect to Raspberry

I am 98% sure both problems are the result of one misconfiguration: files in `/home/pi/.ssh` belong to user `root`. To fix:

```
sudo chown -R pi /home/pi/.ssh
chmod -R u=rw,go= /home/pi/.ssh
```

After that copy relevant parts of `[my user]/.ssh/config` to `/home/pi/.ssh/config`.